# Duplicated JSON result

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have made a simple script to call JSON file and show on the website.

Unfortunately it shows double of the result.
The problem is caused by the pictures. If I remove them the text is shown only once as I want it.

**Here is the script**

```
$(function () {

$('#members p, #members p span, #main_content span').on('click', function () {
    var attr = $(this).attr('data-number');
    if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
        var number = $(this).data('number');
        console.log(number);
        $.ajax("members.json", {
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {

                $(".images_ajax").css('display', 'block');
                $(".images_ajax_sub").append(response[number].img + response[number].text);
            }
        }),
        $(function () {
            $('.close_ajax').click(function () {
                $(".images_ajax_sub h1, .images_ajax_sub p, .images_ajax_sub .iMembers").remove();
                $(".images_ajax").css('display', 'none');
            })
        })
    }
})});
```

If I remove the image from the JSON file then I get only one undefined as the image is missing not two.

**Here is the part of the JSON file**

```
"name": {
"img": "<div class=\"iMembers\"><img src = \"../images/images/images_of_members/some.jpg\"></div>",
"text": "<p>some text</p>"
}
```

Comment: Please provide a demo that replicates problem. Explanation is not clear at all and there is not enough code for us to reproduce it

Comment: You forgot to use `on('click', function (event) { ... event.preventDefaults(); }` (to stop propagation). I'm sure the event is called 2 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that your AJAX call gets fired twice. Take a look at the DOM nodes that the `click` handler is being bound to:

```
$('#members p, #members p span, #main_content span').on('click ...
   ^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Since you don't prevent event bubbling, a click on a `span` triggers the bound event handler, then bubbles up the DOM and triggers again for the `span`'s parent node: `p`. Thus, try binding to either or.

Comment: Yes, i'm sure of this too. He should stop the event propagation at the first call.

Comment: I tried function(e) { e.stopPropagation() and I left only the span element in the jQuery selector. None of these is working. I get back double result. Could you tell me how I should do this?

Comment: I must be an idiot. I put to two places the script src file on the webpage. One was in the head section and one is just before the closing body tag.

Comment: I accepted your answer. It was not the problem in this case but it can be in a different situation. Thank you